# myBinder error using multiple Julia versions

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter, toml

I have [a package](https://github.com/sylvaticus/Bmlt.jl) I am developing with some notebooks I would like to let users play with, and I am using myBinder.org as online computational environment.

All fine, until I replaced in the `[compat]` section of `Project.toml` the entry with Julia with multiple values:

```
julia = "1.3.1,1.3,1.4,1.5"
```

Now I receive [the following error in myBinder](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/sylvaticus/Bmlt.jl/master):

```
Error during build: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,1'
```

If this is a bug, where should I report it ?

EDIT:

This has been addressed in the jupyter discourse forum and resulted in a new issue being created on their repository: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/julia-mybinder-build-error-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10/4755/3